# Accses Bitbucket API (JSON) via Proxy [Java]

Tags: java, json, proxy, bitbucket

I'm trying to access the Bitbucket API to get a JSON file via Java.
But unfortunately I have to route the request through a proxy to have access to it. I've tried everything the last few days but it didn't work. Can either of you help me? The following is my code I used:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xxx-proxy.com", 8080));
      Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx", "xxxx".toCharArray());
            }
    });
      URL url = new URL("https://xxxxx.com/rest/api/1.0/projects");
      HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
      uc.connect();
```

But I get an Exception: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" For me it sounds like the Proxy isn't connected because it works when I just want to use google.com.

I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: paste code that you have tried till now and the error that you are getting. People will be able to help with that info.

Comment: Thanks for the advise I added the code where I think my mistake might be! :)